# Fit Div to Screen but Deduct left margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have below structure

```
<div class="mybox">
<div id="imageslide">
    <a href=""><img src="url" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

It has fixed position and left:300px; means it will start from left side after 300px now I want to make mybox div width fill remaining space of the screen. So I can use 100% to #imageslide which is using some javascript to fits the image in to that div.

All in one I want to make either mybox or imageslide start from left after 300px and fits with the remaining width of the screen and image also should fit with the container accordingly.

**Update:**

The contain image has width and height 100% of parrent div #imageslide so I am unable to override with css. I can remove mybox div that has been additionally added to try with css.
I have tried css but doesn't works.

**This is the site url**----------------
http://saltaa.com/

So here the home page big slider I wan to set is a way so it will starts after left menu column and image will fits according to the screen size in width and height.

**It is really Strange.
Who help me to find the solution I don't know why he/she has removed the answer and may be he voted negative to me. It is strange. At least he/she would allow me to check my file than would accept the answer.**

Comment: Okay, but usually I concern to accept the answer as soon as it works for me.

Comment: It is not about bad but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Yes its a part of template files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
.mybox {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px;
}

var w = $(window).width() - 30;
$('.mybox').css("width", w)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5PPP/1/

Comment: I know may be this is frustrating for you all expert but I don't know noting is working. Even this simple js which should work in anyways this also not working. Let me submit all codes to diagnose what is wrong. I am sure either me is doing wrong or providing incomplete information.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
div.mybox {
    position:absolute;
    left: 300px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#imageslide {
    left: 300px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

img {
    left: 300px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I guess you wanted something else.I have edited it.Please have a look.Even if it doesn't work for you,explain your problem in detail.

Comment: @pixelngrain its not working is not the whole solution of the problem tell where are you getting problem.Add some efforts